# bash: generate machine list based on load

Tags: performance, bash, ssh, awk, load

I'm trying to make a program that sorts machines based on load, but i'm having a hard time parsing the ssh output. What i have so far is this:

```
gen_data()
{
    declare -a machines=("machine1" "machine2" "machine3" "machine4" "machine5")
    for i in ${machines[@]}; do
        ssh $i "hostname && uptime"
    done | awk ' BEGIN {cnt=0} \
         { printf("%s, ", $0)
          cnt++
          if(cnt % 3 == 0) {printf("\n") }
         }' > ~/perf_data
}
#function check_data
# check for load averages (fields 6,7,8) which are greater than 7
check_data()
{
       awk -F"," '{ if($6 < 9.0 && $7 < 9.0 && $8 < 9.0) 
                        {print $0 } 
                  }' ~/perf_data

}
```

most of this code is a modified version of a code that checked machine loads and emailed you if it was too high, but i can't quite get it to print out the machine names or make the perf_data file correctly.

What i'm trying to get is for a list of machines me@machine*.network.com, the program tests the load of the machine, and if it's low enough it prints the machine name:

me@machine1.network.com me@machine5.network.com me@machine10.network.com

that way i can pipe the output to another program that will use those machines.

Since i'm a n00b in awk i really need help with this.

Comment: Post some sample input to the first awk command (i.e. the output of your ssh loop) and the expected output from that awk command given that input, with an explanation of why. Do the same for your second awk script if you need help with that one too.

Comment: added the sample input and output.

Comment: Doesn't look like it to me. Remember - we need the input and output from the perspective of each awk script since THAT is what you're asking us to help you write. Think about what your awk scripts see as input, not what your overall goal is for your whole script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
for i in ${machines[@]}; do
        ssh $i "hostname && uptime"
    done | awk ...
```

use this to make your life easier

```
for m in ${machines[@]}; do
    ssh $i <<'COMMANDS'
        echo "$(hostname):$(uptime)" | awk -F: '{gsub(/,/,"",$NF); print $1, $NF}'
COMMANDS
done > ~/perf_data
```

Then check_data can be

```
check_data() {
    awk '$2 < 9 && $3 < 9 && $4 < 9 {print $1} ~/perf_data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than modifying this script, you can write new one.

Here's a version replacing your script entirely, which fetches the load average in a Linux specific way:

```
for host in machine1 machine2 machine3
do
    ssh "$host" '[ "$(awk "\$1 < 9" /proc/loadavg)" ] && hostname'
done > ~/perf_data
```

Alternately, you can do it through uptime:

```
for host in machine1 machine2 machine3
do
    ssh "$host" '[ "$(uptime | awk -F"[ ,]+" "\$11 < 9")" ] && hostname'
done > ~/perf_data
```

Both these assume that you're interested in the current load, so it checks the 1 minute average rather than also caring about the 15 minute average.

Comment: I did eventually do that. I still wanted to know hot to do it with awk.